# How to flatten nested array (parent->child) tree (of any depth) in MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a nested tree level structure of **item->items** that looks something like this

```
{ "id":"1",
  "type":"panel",
  "items": [
    { "id":"2", "type":"input", },
    { "id":"4", "type":"group", "items": [ 
        { "id":"5", "type":"input" },
        { "id":"6", "type":"panel", "items":[...] },
      ]
    }
  ]}
```

I'm looking to flatten the tree and get a single array list of all items like this:

```
[ { "id":"1", "type":"panel", },
  { "id":"2", "type":"input", },
  { "id":"4", "type":"panel", },
  { "id":"5", "type":"input", },
  ...
]
```

Is there a generic way to flatten the tree (that would work for any depth level)?

All answers I found here just manually $unwind each child level (I can't predict the number of levels) nor do I have reference to parent to use traverse with $graphLookup.

Or something like **{'$*.items'}**?

Answer (score 1):

MQL doesn't have functions, so we can't recur, if we find a array.
Maybe there is a way to do it with MQL and 1 query.

But there is way to do it fast with more than 1 query.
The bellow example is 1 level/query.

With small change it can do 10 level/query or 100 level/query etc
so only 1 query will be needed, but we will do some redadent attempts to flatten arrays even if they are empty.

First 1 small modification.
Add 1 field  on all documents `"all-items": [{"id": "$id","type": "$type"}]`
and removed the top level "id" and "type". Like bellow

```
aggregate(
[ {
  "$project" : {
    "all-items" : [ {
      "id" : "$id",
      "type" : "$type"
    } ],
    "items" : 1
  }
} ]
)
```

Modified data

```js
[
  {
    "all-items": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "type": "panel"
      }
    ],
    "items": [...like it was...]
  }
]
```

And now we can do it with multiple queries 1 per/level

[First call, code example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YsXQbBSjRKC)
[Second call, code example, with the result of first call](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SqrNYhe2_xT)

Third call we dont need, while will be false.

In each call we do `$out`, and we aggregate on the result of previous call.

`while(there_is_1_document_with_not_empty_items[]) (send 1 find query)`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "level-nlevel": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$items",
          "initialValue": [
            [],
            []
          ],
          "in": {
            "$let": {
              "vars": {
                "info": "$$value",
                "i": "$$this"
              },
              "in": {
                "$let": {
                  "vars": {
                    "level": {
                      "$arrayElemAt": [
                        "$$info",
                        0
                      ]
                    },
                    "nlevel": {
                      "$arrayElemAt": [
                        "$$info",
                        1
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "in": [
                    {
                      "$concatArrays": [
                        "$$level",
                        [
                          {
                            "id": "$$i.id",
                            "type": "$$i.type"
                          }
                        ]
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "$cond": [
                        {
                          "$isArray": [
                            "$$i.items"
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "$concatArrays": [
                            "$$nlevel",
                            "$$i.items"
                          ]
                        },
                        "$$nlevel"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "all-items": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$all-items",
          {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$level-nlevel",
              0
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "items": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$level-nlevel",
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This flattens per document(no `$unwind` is used), if you want to flatten all collection, `$unwind` one time after the while ends the `$all-items`.

Comment: i wrote this, total forgotten about the `$function` option which is much better, dont use this use the other solution described above, i just leave it here as a possible way to do it in MQL.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a mongodb query language aggregation sage that supports flatting to an unknown depth, but [$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) would allow you to execute a method against the document

here is a javascript example:

```
var fn = function(items) {
    var ret = [];
    var toCheck = [...items];
    while (toCheck.length) {
        var nxtToCheck = [];
        for (var item of toCheck) {
            ret.push({ id: item.id, type: item.type });
            nxtToCheck.push(...(item.items || []));
        }
        toCheck = nxtToCheck;
    }
    return ret;
}

db.myCol.aggregate([
    { $match: {} },
    { $addFields: { allItems: { $function: { body: fn, args: ["$items"], lang: "js" } } } }
]);
```